# How can I apply CAGradient to down part of the pic?

Tags: ios, cagradientlayer

```
gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);

gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
```

It is coming for upper part but not for down part of the pic please help me?

Comment: You have set the end point to be half way from the top. For the bottom half start at y = 0.5 and end with y = 1.0.

Comment: I have already  tried that but not coming

Comment: Can you show your code and more information about what you want and what you see.

Comment: cell.hotelBg.layer.mask = gradientMask;
               gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
                
                gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
                
                
                gradientMask.frame = cell.hotelBg.layer.bounds;
                gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,
                                    (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
                [cell.hotelBg.layer addSublayer:gradientMask];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to create a gradient which fills the full height. Once it is working, try changing the start and end values. You issue could be related to how you are creating it, how you are setting the frame or it could relate to using `clearColor`. Might be worth using something else like red first.

Add property for the gradient layer to your cell class so you can access it:

```
@property CAGradientLayer *gradient;
```

Add this function so you can create a gradient layer easily.

```
CAGradientLayer *createBackgroundGradientLayer(CGRect forFrame,UIColor *fromColour,UIColor *toColour){
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[fromColour CGColor],(id)[toColour CGColor], nil];
    gradient.frame = forFrame;

    return gradient;
}
```

Where you create the gradient in your cell do the following: Really you want to do this in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad` so the frame size is correct.

```
// Create new gradient layer
self.gradient = createBackgroundGradientLayer(cell.hotelBg.layer.bounds,[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor clearColor]);

// Add the gradient layer to the back.
[cell.hotelBg.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

You need to reset the background gradient layer frame when layout changes. Override the `layoutSubviews` method in your custom cell.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Re-align the background gradient layer to the correct bounds.
    self.gradient.frame=self.hotelBg.layer.bounds;
}
```

Assumption is that `self.hotelBg` is some sort of view which has constraints etc that size it properly.